# Moment.js - How to convert time formats correctly to properly do time zone conversions

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

The code below is at moment-timezone documentation and it works perfectly. The result is what I want.
https://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

let timeInput = "2014-06-01 12:00";


var newYork    = moment.tz(timeInput, "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

console.log(newYork.format("LLLL"));    // Sunday, June 1, 2014 12:00 PM
console.log(losAngeles.format("LLLL")); // Sunday, June 1, 2014 9:00 AM
console.log(london.format("LLLL"));     // Sunday, June 1, 2014 5:00 PM
```

**The problem**

I am using a date/time material picker widget that outputs a date object. When I try to format the date/time the result is the following:

```
let timeAndDate = moment(dateObj).format("LLL");

// Thursday, December 26, 2019 12:00 PM
// I can also get "2019-12-26T00:00:00-08:00" by doing format()
```

In the code below I expect the time offsets to be the same as the initial code I posted above - it is not.

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

let timeInput = "Thursday, December 26, 2019 12:00 PM";


var newYork    = moment.tz(timeInput, "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

console.log(newYork.format("LLLL"));    // Thursday, December 26, 2019 7:00 AM
console.log(losAngeles.format("LLLL")); // Thursday, December 26, 2019 4:00 AM
console.log(london.format("LLLL"));     // Thursday, December 26, 2019 12:00 PM
```

My question is, how do I take a date that is formatted like this:
"Thursday, December 26, 2019 12:00 PM" and convert it to format like "2019-12-26 12:00" so that I can convert between time zones correctly in my app?

Comment: `var newYork    = moment.tz("Thursday, December 26, 2019 12:00 PM", "dddd, MMM DD, YYYY h:mm a", "America/New_York");`

Answer (score 1):

Use `newYork.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")`